# RDD[ x : Vector[String] ] to RDD[x: Vector[String] + Iterator : Vector[String] ]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

DocsRDD :

```
RDD[Vector[String]]
```

DocsRDD :

```
Vector(Doc1.txt, Doc2.txt, Doc5.txt)
Vector(Doc4.txt, Doc3.txt)
Vector(Doc6.txt, Doc9.txt)
```

What I want is Just all the Dual pairs of docs, for example for DocsRDD i want

AllDualDocsRDD :

```
Vector(Doc1.txt, Doc2.txt)
Vector(Doc1.txt, Doc5.txt)
Vector(Doc2.txt, Doc5.txt)
Vector(Doc4.txt, Doc3.txt)
Vector(Doc6.txt, Doc9.txt)
```

Below is a sample of my code(I am new to Spark,Scala).

```
val AllDualDocsRDD = DocsRDD.map(e => if (e.size > 2) {
                            val V_iter = (1 to e.size).flatMap(e.combinations).filter(_.size == 2).toVector
                            V_iter.foreach(println)
                            //Here I Cannot put V_iter : scala.Vector[Vector[String]]
                        }
                        else e)
```

But it seems i have hit the wall! Does anyone know how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sc.parallelize(
  Seq(Vector("Doc1.txt", "Doc2.txt", "Doc5.txt"))
).flatMap(v => v.combinations(Math.min(v.size, 2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a direct flatmap on the RDD like this:

```
val AllDualDocsRDD = DocsRDD.flatMap(  x => {
                                     if( x.size > 2){
                                            x.combinations(2).toSeq
                                        }
                                     else Seq(x)
                                    }
                            )
```

This does the job.